# Eclipse c++ how to reinclude excluded file from build

Tags: c++, eclipse

In eclipse is possibile to exclude from compilation any resource.

How:

- select *.cpp
- right-click with mouse:

  - Resource Configuration -> Exlude from build

How to reinclude?

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse there's not a similar way to reinclude resource, like:

- Resource Configuration -> Reinclude from build

You need to go in Project Proprerties (Alt+Enter) and go:

```
C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols
```

Select tab

```
Source Location
```

and expand your project's folder: here you can select filter that you want to remove and click on "**Edit Filter**" and then "**Remove**".